# Cannot access QML singleton residing in same dir

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, importerror, project-structure

I'm getting this error:

> qrc:/qml/Accessor.qml:5: ReferenceError: MySingleton is not defined

My project structure:

```
| main.cpp
| main.qml
| qml/
+--- Accessor.qml
+--- MySingleton.qml
+--- qmldir
```

Contents of the files:

*main.cpp:*

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "qml/"

Accessor {
}
```

*qml/Accessor.qml*:

```
import QtQml 2.2
//import qml 1.0

QtObject {
    property int foo: MySingleton.foo
}
```

*qml/MySingleton.qml*:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQml 2.2

QtObject {
    property int foo: 0
}
```

*qml/qmldir*:

```
module qml

singleton MySingleton 1.0 MySingleton.qml
```

*qml.qrc*:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>qml/Accessor.qml</file>
        <file>qml/MySingleton.qml</file>
        <file>qml/qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Uncommenting the `import qml 1.0` in Accessor.qml doesn't help. But when Accessor.qml is in the project root, it works fine.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I had to add `import "."` into `Accessor.qml`.

Comment: It is a long standing bug. Either import the dot, or register the singleton from C++.

Comment: @dtech I didn't even know that `import "."` let you access `pragma Singleton` objects without registering from c++. Thanks!